# IE8 javascript error - Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use the below function but get a error Object does not support this propery of method in javascript

```
 transactionData.forEach(function(e,i,a){
        var found = $.inArray(e["dataSource"],transactionData);
        if (found > -1){
        return true;
        }
        else{
        colors.push(e["dataSource"])
        }   
    })
```

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not supported by [IE versions less than **9**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility). To make it working either use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), or try jQuery (since you are using jQuery) alternative method [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$.each(transactionData, function(key, value) {
    // ...
});
```